# Hololens - Azure spatial anchors - error : WindowsMR and OpenXR plugins cannot be used together, uninstall the Windows MR plugin to use OpenXR

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

I have an error when configurating a azure spatial anchor for a unity project (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/how-tos/setup-unity-project?tabs=xr-plugin-framework%2Cunity-2020%2Cunity-package-mixed-reality-feature-tool%2CExtraConfigurationsHoloLens#download-asa-packages)

I'm following the tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/quickstarts/get-started-unity-hololens?tabs=azure-portal#create-a-spatial-anchors-resource and I'm trying to import the ASA SDK but I get the error: ** Assets\AzureSpatialAnchors.Examples\Scripts\OpenXRInput\WindowsMRGestures.cs(6,8): error CS1029: #error: '"WindowsMR and OpenXR plugins cannot be used together, uninstall the Windows MR plugin to use OpenXR"'
**

I don't know why, I'm using the Azure Spatial Anchors SDK versions 2.13.3 which should be able to support both plug-ins (Azure Spatial Anchors SDK Core and Azure Spatial Anchors SDK for Windows). And installed the dependencies required for OpenXR and windows MR.

If you know how to solve this issue so that both plug-ins can be installed at the same time, I would be glad to know, as I have spent quite some time on it.

Answer (score 0):

For this one, the OpenXR plugin is all that is needed.

Microsoft is advising to use LTS versions with OpenXR:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version

> Unity 2020.3 LTS or 2021.3 LTS (Recommended)
>
> We recommend that you use the latest patch version of Unity 2020.3 LTS
> or 2021.3 LTS and their recommended version of Unity plugins,
> together with the latest Mixed Reality OpenXR plugin.

Here are the details on just using OpenXR:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/how-tos/setup-unity-project?tabs=xr-plugin-framework%2Cunity-2020%2Cunity-package-mixed-reality-feature-tool%2CExtraConfigurationsHoloLens#download-asa-packages

> The XR Plug-in Framework is only supported on ASA SDK version 2.9.0 or
> later. To target the XR Plug-in Framework, use Unity 2020.3 (LTS), and
> AR Foundation 4.1.7 with the following packages, depending on your
> platform:
>
> ```
> Mixed Reality OpenXR Plugin: 1.1.2
> ```